# ExtJS ListView - Set background color for specific row

Tags: listview, extjs

I have a ExtJS ListView as below:

```
var myList = new Ext.list.ListView({
    id:'mylist-view',
    store: mystore,
    multiSelect: true,
    emptyText: 'No content to display',
    reserveScrollOffset: true,
    columns: [{
    header: 'Header-1',
    width: .3,
    dataIndex: 'data-1'
    },{
    header: 'Header-2',
    width: .3,
    dataIndex: 'data-2',
    align: 'right'
    },{
    header: 'Header-3',
    width: .3,
    dataIndex: 'data-3',
    align: 'right'
    }],
    });
```

I want to set a different background color for a specific row. How can I do it?

I referred some other solutions provided for the similar issue and tried the following:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, ds) {
    return record.get('data-1') == 'Total' ? 'background-color: #EEEEEE' : '';
    }
}
```

But, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) function should return name of css class, not css style definition.

So you should have in your `viewConfig` something like this:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, ds) {
    return record.get('data-1') == 'Total' ? 'myRowClass' : '';
    }
}
```

And in your CSS file:

```
.myRowClass .x-grid-cell {
     background-color: #EEEEEE
}
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3p8**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function (record) {
        if (record && record.get('data-1') == 'Total') return 'data-available-row';
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.data-available-row > td {
    background-color: #f7e5e5 !important;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle:

[Changing row color based on the row value](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3pa)

**Remarks:**
Listview just a `Ext.grid.Panel`

I am adding my data store code below for you reference:

```
    var mystore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ 
        fields: [ 'data-1', {name:'data-2', type: 'integer'},
    {name:'data-3', type:'float'}], 
        data: [ {"data-1":"Data-1","data-2":83,"data-3":3.2},
    {"data-1":"Total","data-2":73,"data-3":4.0} ] 
    });
```

Comment: I tried the above solution but no difference. I am using ListView in my code but not Panel. I understand that Panel is the parent class for ListView still this is not working

Comment: Are you sure? It's working. Try to re-open fiddle example. I changed grid panel with Listview!

Comment: Can you please try the same with the code I have pasted in my question? I tried all the solutions provided but it is not working for me.



var mystore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
             
             fields: [
                 'data-1',
                 {name:'data-2', type: 'integer'},
                 {name:'data-3', type:'float'}
             ],
             data: [
     {"data-1":"Data-1","data-2":83,"data-3":3.2},
     {"data-1":"Total","data-2":73,"data-3":4.0}
             ]
         });

Comment: it seems to me your problem related with string compare. Try to change `'Total'` to `"Total"`. I modified the fiddle with your data. It's still working!